# No matching function for call to std::transform, unresolved overloaded function type

Tags: c++, stl, compiler-errors, std

I have the following, correct and compiling code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>

template<typename K, typename V>
void write_map(const std::multimap<K, V> mm)
{
    std::cout << "MultiMap content:"<< std::endl << std::endl;
    for(auto it = mm.begin(); it != mm.end(); it++)
        std::cout << it->first << "\t" << it->second << std::endl;
}

template<typename K, typename V>
void write_map(const std::map<K, V> m)
{
    std::cout << "Map content:"<< std::endl << std::endl;
    for(auto it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); it++)
        std::cout << it->first << "\t" << it->second << std::endl;
}

template<typename KV, typename VK>
std::pair<VK, KV> flip_pair(const std::pair<KV, VK> &p)
{
    return std::pair<VK, KV>(p.second, p.first);
}

template<typename KV, typename VK>
std::multimap<VK, KV> flip_map(const std::map<KV, VK> &src)
{
    std::multimap<VK, KV> dst;
    // LINE_B follows
    std::transform(src.begin(), src.end(), std::inserter(dst, dst.begin()), flip_pair<KV, VK>);
    return dst;
}

int main(void)
{
    std::map<std::string, uint32_t> m_words_map1;

    std::pair<std::string, uint32_t> p1("aaa", 2);
    std::pair<std::string, uint32_t> p2("bbb", 1);
    m_words_map1.insert(p1);
    m_words_map1.insert(p2);
    write_map(m_words_map1);
    // LINE_A follows
    std::multimap<uint32_t, std::string> sorted_multimap1 = flip_map(m_words_map1);
    write_map(sorted_multimap1);
}
```

Which I compile with success on `Debian 7.8 x64`, `gcc 4.7.2` with

```
g++ foo.cpp -o foo -std=c++11
```

After that, I've embedded this bunch of functions in a complex project which uses CMake (here follows CMakeLists.txt)

```
file(GLOB_RECURSE CORE_OBJ core/*.cpp)
file(GLOB_RECURSE LIB_OBJ_CPP lib/*.cpp)
file(GLOB_RECURSE LIB_OBJ_HPP lib/*.hpp)
file(GLOB_RECURSE LIB_OBJ_C lib/*.c)
list(APPEND LIB_OBJ ${LIB_OBJ_CPP} ${LIB_OBJ_HPP} ${LIB_OBJ_C})
file(GLOB_RECURSE USR_CPP usr/*.cpp)
file(GLOB_RECURSE USR_HPP usr/*.hpp)
list(APPEND USR_OBJ ${USR_CPP} ${USR_HPP})
list(APPEND BLOCKMON_LINK_LIBS pcap pthread boost_system boost_filesystem)
list(APPEND INCLUDE_DIRS lib/external/pugixml/src lib lib/external/factory lib/external/more lib/external/ lib/hash lib/bloom lib/pat core messages blocks ipfix core/block core/message core/composition core/scheduler core/time  ${USR_INCL})
include_directories( ${INCLUDE_DIRS} )
set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -O3 -march=native -Wall -g -std=c++0x")
add_definitions(-D_GLIBCXX_USE_SCHED_YIELD -D_GLIBCXX_USE_NANOSLEEP)
target_link_libraries(blockmonpy blockmoncore boost_python)
link_directories(/usr/local/lib)
list(APPEND BLOCKMON_XML-RPC_LINK_LIBS xmlrpc_client++ xmlrpc_client xmlrpc++ xmlrpc xmlrpc_util xmlrpc_xmlparse xmlrpc_xmltok curl xmlrpc_packetsocket xmlrpc_server_abyss++ xmlrpc_server++ xmlrpc_server_abyss xmlrpc_server xmlrpc_abyss  pthread)
list(APPEND BLOCKMON_LINK_LIBS ${BLOCKMON_XML-RPC_LINK_LIBS})
target_link_libraries(blockmonWithXmlRPC blockmoncore ${BLOCKMON_LINK_LIBS})
add_library(blockmoncore SHARED ${CORE_OBJ} ${MSG_OBJ} ${IPFIX_OBJ} ${LIB_OBJ} ${BLOCKS_OBJ} ${USR_OBJ})
target_link_libraries(blockmoncore ${BLOCKMON_LINK_LIBS})
add_executable(blockmon bin/blockmon.cpp)
target_link_libraries(blockmon blockmoncore ${BLOCKMON_LINK_LIBS})
```

In a source file of this project, the snippet is **mirrored** into a source file, without any modification. But here, `make` stops and complains abouts the following. I flavoured output to better bind line numbers with errors:

```
In instantiation of ‘std::multimap<VK, KV> flip_map(const std::map<K, V>&) [with KV = std::basic_string<char>; VK = unsigned int]’:
LINE A:   required from here
LINE B: error: no matching function for call to ‘transform(std::map<std::basic_string<char>, unsigned int>::const_iterator, std::map<std::basic_string<char>, unsigned int>::const_iterator, std::insert_iterator<std::multimap<unsigned int, std::basic_string<char> > >, <unresolved overloaded function type>)’
    note: candidates are:
    note: _OIter std::transform(_IIter, _IIter, _OIter, _UnaryOperation) [with _IIter = std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, unsigned int> >; _OIter = std::insert_iterator<std::multimap<unsigned int, std::basic_string<char> > >; _UnaryOperation = std::pair<unsigned int, std::basic_string<char> > (Class::*)(const std::pair<std::basic_string<char>, unsigned int>&)]
    note:   no known conversion for argument 4 from ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ to ‘std::pair<unsigned int, std::basic_string<char> > (Class::*)(const std::pair<std::basic_string<char>, unsigned int>&)’
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_algo.h:4977:5: note: template<class _IIter1, class _IIter2, class _OIter, class _BinaryOperation> _OIter std::transform(_IIter1, _IIter1, _IIter2, _OIter, _BinaryOperation)
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_algo.h:4977:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
LINE B: note:   candidate expects 5 arguments, 4 provided
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your error message (grep **`<unresolved overloaded function type>`**), my wild guess is that you have somehow overloaded the function `flip_pair<>` you pass to `std::transform` in other translation unit. [`std::transform` is a template function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform), and its functor is passed as a template type. If you have overloads, then `std::transform` won't be able to deduce the type of the transforming function, hence the error. See a toy example [here](http://ideone.com/DuMvJ4), which spits out essentially the same error message.

Comment: After moving the incriminated functions to an **Utils** static class, renaming `flip_pair` and `flip_map` to something else, all worked up. But still no idea on the source of overloading, hehe :-)

Comment: @alpenwolf try doing a `grep -Rn "name_of_culprit"` inside the source folder so you can locate the additional overload.

Comment: @Patrizio Bertoni I also moved the flip_pair and flip_map to namespace and renamed them as suggested. Works like a charm now. Thanks.